# How to create a geometry generator symbol using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I am trying to use PyQGIS to convert a Fill Symbol Layer into a geometry generator Symbol Layer in a rule-based renderer with 300 rules.

I am able to iterate over the rules and return each rule's symbol and then the respective (unique) Symbol Layer. I know there's a changeSymbolLayer()

What I am failing to do, is to create a QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer to overwrite the existing symbol layer. Until now, the code is something like this:

```
layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
rules = layer.renderer().rootRule().children()

for rule in rules:
    label = rule.label()
    symbol_layer = rule.symbol().symbolLayer(0)
    print(symbol_layer)
    color = symbol_layer.color()
    generator = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer()
    generator.setFillColor(color)
    generator.setGeometryExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0,generator)
```

In this case the QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer() fails by saying that I am not able to instantiate.

I am not understanding how to create the new symbol to apply on each rule.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a constructor. Can you use `.create()` or `.clone()` instead?

Comment: `generator = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})` seems to work

Comment: To clone() l need an existing symbol layer already, right? Not sure how to use create. I have seen it in other symbol layers types, but wasn't able to figure out how to apply to geometry generators.

Comment: Since you are programmatically setting its properties, @DrorBogin's creation of an "empty" generator for you to fill looks good.

Comment: The documentation about the actual `create` properties is a bit lacking, but it seems you can create an empty one and just set everything later

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like the only way to create an empty `QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer` is by using:

```
QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
```

So changing just that should make the rest of the code work:

```
layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
rules = layer.renderer().rootRule().children()

for rule in rules:
    label = rule.label()
    symbol_layer = rule.symbol().symbolLayer(0)
    print(symbol_layer)
    color = symbol_layer.color()
    generator = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({})
    generator.setFillColor(color)
    generator.setGeometryExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().changeSymbolLayer(0,generator)
```

Comment: .create({}) was the missing piece. Worked like a charm!