# Set the Units of a QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer object in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry-generator

I am pretty much following the procedure of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/384787/86042) answer but I can't get my head around as to where to set the 'Units' from 'Map Units' (default) to `Millimeters` that is.

So far, I tried several variants to define a unit type and set the symbol layer to it:

```
millimeters = QgsUnitTypes.DistanceUnit.Millimeters
renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(1).setUnits(millimeters)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `QgsUnitTypes.RenderMillimeters`.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

mm = QgsUnitTypes.RenderMillimeters
layer.renderer().symbol().symbolLayer(1).setUnits(mm)
```

`symbolLayer(1)` must be an instance of `QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer`.

You can find [different unit types](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgis_8h_source.html#l03029) in source code.